# How to perform multiple JSON connections in the same viewController

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

In a viewController I am using the following code to execute a JSON connection:

In viewDidLoad method:

```
 //URL definition where php file is hosted
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/empresastodaslist.php"];
    // URL request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //URL connection to the internet
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


//methods to perform the connection and population of data

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    [data appendData:thedata];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //if data received network indicator not visible
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    //array waterfalls populated via JSON from database
    categorias = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    NSLog(@"NUMERO DE EMPRESAS = %lu"
          , (unsigned long)[categorias count]);
}
```

I need to do the same in the same viewController but requesting two other different PHP files to create two more NSArrays.

I don't find problems just making a copy of the code inside the viewDidLoad method, renaming NSURl / NSURLRequest and changing the URL for the two others URLs, but I don't know how to implement the connection methods for the two new URLs.

Comment: The reason the connection delegate methods pass the`NSURLConnection` as the first parameter is so that you can check it.  You have three `NSURLConnection`s in flight, so when one of the callback methods is called, you need to check the `connection` parameter to see which one it is.

Comment: Thank you @jeffamaphone, would you mind showing me in an answer how should I check the connection parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//PROCESSING FIRST CONNECTION
NSURL *first_connection_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/empresastodaslist.php"];
NSURLRequest *first_connection_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:first_connection_url];
NSURLConnection *first_connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:first_connection_request delegate:self];

//PROCESSING SECOND CONNECTION
NSURL *second_connection_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_of_second_string.php"];
NSURLRequest *second_connection_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:second_connection_url];
NSURLConnection *second_connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:second_connection_request delegate:self];


//methods to perform the connection and population of data

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if(connection==first_connection){
         data_for_first_connection = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    else if(connection==second_connection){
         data_for_second_connection = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    if(connection==first_connection){
         [data_for_first_connection appendData:thedata];
    }
    else if(connection==second_connection){
         [data_for_second_connection appendData:thedata];
    }
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //if data received network indicator not visible
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    if(connection==first_connection) {
        //array waterfalls populated via JSON from database
    categorias = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    NSLog(@"NUMERO DE EMPRESAS = %lu"
      , (unsigned long)[categorias count]);
    }
    else if(connection==second_connection){
        // PROCESS TO BE DONE FOR SECOND CONNECTION
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dream, and at methods didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData?

Comment: Edited answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

**request1**

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"results"]);
    }];
```

**request2**

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"results"]);
}];
```

**request3**

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request3 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"results"]);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. May be it will help you...

If you have two NSURLConnection like:

```
NSURLConnection *Connect1 = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:firstRequest delegate:self];

NSURLConnection *Connect2 = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:firstRequest delegate:self];
```

Then check like this:

//methods to perform the connection and population of data

```
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    [data appendData:thedata];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    if( [connection isEqual: Connect1] ){
        // do connection 1 stuff here
    }
    else if( [connection isEqual: Connect2] ){
        // do connection 2 stuff here
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you IOS Developer, and at methods didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData? I guess I have also to allocate and append the data for the other two connects.

Comment: @mvasco if you are not calling all the connection method at the same time then there is no requirement of creating multiple NSData object. IF you call all the methods at the simultaneously then you have to create multiple NSData objects as per connection count

Answer (score 0):

invoking multiple URLS requires You know well networking / concurrency and thread.
You can manage a random "arrival" of data and synch them, plus errors.
(You can get contents of 2ns URL and after a while an error in Url 1...)

I strongly suggest to ask your network guys to send all JSON once, (if not very big...)

You have a lot of advantage:
1) better network efficiency (only one call)
2) only one error to manage
3) no sync / coherence problems
4) All / nothing logic on data
5) far more testable.